# IOS - failed to start the app

Tags: ios

I just tried to run my test app and I got this error:

> 2012-06-16 09:09:10.737 BusinessPlan[832:f803] Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'MainStoryboard_iPhone' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

How do I set the designated entry point? And what is that?

Also, when I was going through their intro tutorials, the last time I ran the simulator was on the color-change step, and that worked for me.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In your story board file select the `viewController` you want to assign as first controller and check on `is initial View Controller` check the image

[image]

Comment: This is what I meant by my slightly rambling response. Kudos to Omar.

Comment: There's also the arrow on the left that points to the initial View Controller. Same thing as the checkbox but cooler (you can drag it between View Controllers).

Answer (score 2):

I've not done an immense amount with storyboards yet, mostly with the older nib/xib based flow.
However...

This looks like: When the app launches it creates an instance of UIApplication. This instance then needs to know what storyboard to go and connect to in order to create the user interface.
Looks like that link is missing in your app.
In the olden days you would either explicitly tell the app, in code, which nib to load or else you would have the link specified in interface builder.
I believe in the world of storyboards it is now more abstract and disconnecting the interface from the app by mistake is not easy to determine and fix.
I would recommend first going through the programming guide for storyboards on Apples developer site, or else start looking in the story board file for missing connections to it's delegate.

This isn't an answer per se, apologies, more of a guide to where to find one.