# My iOS App is having a Black Screen after Splash Screen, but it shows the status bar. iOS SDK 5.1

Tags: ios, screen, xcode4.3

I am using the Tab Bar View App, and am using a storyboard, my Xcode Version is 4.3.3.
Basically my app used to load fine, but then I added a third view and third view controllers and it wouldn't load properly so I deleted them and now it won't load properly:/ It loads the splash screen but it doesn't go any further.

Here is my AppDelegate.h

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//  Work App for Dad
//
//  Created by Alfie Hopkin on 17/06/2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *FirstViewController;

@end
```

And my AppDelegate.m

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  Work App for Dad
//
//  Created by Alfie Hopkin on 17/06/2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize FirstViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [_window addSubview:FirstViewController.view];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you certain, that your FirstViewController is getting loaded properly? Have you tried stepping into the various steps to check that all of them are getting executed properly? Because you see...I am not familiar with the Storyboard mode, but I fail to see any 'loading' code for your FirstViewController.

Comment: With the error you're getting, here's a link to something that looks worth checking out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063736/ios-failed-to-start-the-app

Comment: I love You Phillip! i tried that but i tried it on the FirstViewController not the Tab Bar Controller:) Thank you soo much, do you have twitter or a youtube account? i will give you shoutouts:)

Comment: Youtube link no longer works...

Answer (score 1):

did you forget to set the your custom classes for the viewcontrollers in storyboard's identity inspector?

Comment: nope the classes are set up to the correct viewcontrollers, thanks for the advise anyway:)

Comment: happened to me yesterday after deleting and dragging out everything again, hoped i wasn't the only one ^^ initial View controller is set too?

Comment: I fixed it now, from a little help from Phillip Mills, heres the link, if it's helpful to you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063736/ios-failed-to-start-the-app